# Consulta sql para fecha

Tags: sql

Tengo en la base de datos registros con fechas en el siguiente formato **08-OCT-2022**, como puedo hacer una consulta de registros que estén dentro de 2 fechas distintas, por ejemplo **06-OCT-2022** a **08-OCT-2022**?

La columna de las fechas está en tipo **TEXT**

Comment: Recomiendo cambies esa columna a YYYY-MM-DD y las consultas las podrás hacer de forma directa sin conversiones, [sigue estándares](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) en tus implementaciones. Por otro lado, creo que debe funcionar BETWEEN combinado con `to_date(...)` (Oracle), `CONVERT(DATETIME, ...)` (SQLServer) o `STR_TO_DATE(...)` (MySql).

Comment: Cambia las columnas a un tipo fecha antes de que siga creciendo la tabla.